# Costmap configuration (costmap common_params.yaml)

Tags: ros, costmap, ir

I have a robot equipped with IR sensors, I don't have lidar. I don't understand how can I set my parameters in this file (costmap common_params.yaml) , what should I put instead of LesarScan (Note I will have more than 1 IR)

```
obstacle_range: 0.02
raytrace_range: 1
footprint: [[-0.145, -0.145], [-0.145, 0.145], [0.145, 0.145], [0.145, -0.145]]
inflation_radius: 0.55
transform_tolerance: 0.5
observation_sources: scan
scan:
 data_type: LaserScan
 topic: scan
 marking: true
 clearing: true
map_type: costmap
```

My robot is round shape and I have 4 IR sensors 1 at each sides

Comment: Interesting question - I have 7 forward looking IR sensors that return a non-linear intensity based on distance and surface reflectivity (they are not TimeOfFlight IR range sensors).  I plan to subscribe to my IR intensities and create a /scan topic with the approximate range values to input to slam-toolbox.

It will be interesting to see if folks recommend you create a topic with a vector of your four readings, or create a scan topic with your 4 valid readings, min/max, -180->+90 or how ever yours are ordered.